# Output a repos URLs using Octokit.rb

Tags: ruby, github-api, octokit

I'm attempting to list details of a Github accounts repos using [Octokit.rb](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb), but can't seem to find the associated URLs.

In the first instance all I need to do is authenticate with the Github API using OAuth and output the details to the console. Here's a basic example so far:

```
client = Octokit::Client.new :access_token => 'my_token'

client.repos.each do |repo|
    puts repo.name
    puts repo.description
    # html_url & clone_url go here.
end
```

I'm sure I've overlooked something obvious, but what do you need to do to find the `html_url`, `clone_url` etc (as per the [API](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#get)) for each repository?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out it was obvious after all:

```
client = Octokit::Client.new :access_token => 'my_token'

client.repos.each do |repo|
    puts repo.name
    puts repo.description

    # find the urls
    puts repo.rels[:html].href
    puts repo.rels[:git].href
    puts repo.rels[:clone].href
    puts repo.rels[:ssh].href
end
```

Comment: How do you know that you have to put ".href" at the end? Is is in the API documentation?